# Struggling with Twitter Oauth callback

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to implement Twitter login in my application and I'm having some issues with the callback of the `request_token` step. I registered `http://localhost:8200/oauth/callback` as a callback URL in my Twitter app but I get this error when trying to login:

```js
{
  statusCode: 403,
  data: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error code="415">Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings</error></errors>`
}
```

What I don't understand is that it is working if I set the callback URL to `http://localhost:8200`.

What should I do to make it work with `http://localhost:8200/oauth/callback`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error: the callback url in my Oauth instance didn't match the one set in the Twitter app